# Load multiple videos without playing

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm building a video player where each scene is filmed from multiple angles. All videos are hosted on YouTube. I'd like to allow the user to be able to switch between angles seamlessly during playback.

To facilitate this, I need a way to load videos from YouTube without playing them. That way I can load alternate angles in the background while one angle is playing. When the user switches angle, the new angle should be at least partially loaded and ready to play immediately.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to load a video without playing it.

The [`loadVideoById`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#loadVideoById) method autoplays the video as soon as the request to load the video has returned so that won't work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to cue up a video and force it to pre-buffer.

You can load (as opposed to cue) a video and then immediately pause it, and it may or may not pre-buffer, but that's dependent on a number of factors and is outside your control as someone using the API.